# Select distinct rows where value is 8 only when 8 is the max value

Tags: sql-server, select, group-by, max, distinct

My table looks like this:

```
NetbiosName    ProductVersion

Computer1             8

Computer1             9

Computer2             8

Computer2             8

Computer3             7

Computer4             9

Computer4             10

Computer5             7

Computer5             8

Computer6             10

Computer7             8
```

I want to display only the distinct computers where ProductVersion = 8 but ONLY if  8 is the max value
For the above example it should look like this:

```
NetbiosName    ProductVersion

Computer2             8

Computer5             8

Computer7             8
```

Comment: Use GROUP BY and HAVING.

Comment: This is a basic `group by` and a having clause on the max of the Productversion. If this is homework, that should give you enough pointers to solve the question. *(teach a man to fish sort to speak)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
SELECT
    t.NetbiosName,
    MAX(t.ProductVersion) as ProductVersion
FROM
    table1 as t
GROUP BY
    t.NetbiosName
HAVING MAX(t.ProductVersion)=8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct(NetbiosName),ProductVersion from table where ProductVersion='8'
```

Comment: This does not cover ...but ONLY if 8 is the max value